# Как динамически определить возвращаемый тип в зависимости от аргумента функции

Tags: javascript, typescript, fetch

Есть клиентское API, набор функций, выполняющих запрос на сервер.
К сожалению, серверное API написано не идеально, и ответ приходит в разных форматах.
На стороне клиента, эти форматы я привожу к стандартному типу

Успех

```
interface SuccessResponse<T> {
  data: T;
  status: 'ok';
}
```

Ошибка

```
export interface ErrorResponse {
  error: Error; // Тип Error
  status: 'error';
}
```

Сама функция в упрощенном виде выглядит вот так.

```
  return fetch(url, method, data)
    .then((res): SuccessResponse<User> => res) 
    .catch((error): ErrorResponse => error);
```

Тип в данном примере зависит от аргументов `url`
и `method`

**Обратите внимание, что в дженерик я подставляю тип `User`**, это "жесткая" запись, для определенного URLа `/use/auth` и метода `GET`

Если я поменяю URL на `book/add` `POST`, то ответ от сервера уже будет другой. Соответственно, мне надо как-то переключить тип на `SuccessResponse<Book>`. Наверное, по-хорошему, надо делать как-то так: `SuccessResponse<url, method>`, но я не представляю, как переключить тип `data` в интерфейсе `SuccessResponse`. Подскажите, можно ли как-то динамически поменять тип?

Хотелось бы оставить названия типов User и Book, как есть, для лучшей читаемости, и просто связать их в каком-нибудь объекте с нужным URLом и уже с помощью него делать выборку. Пока мало опыта с TS не представляю как это правильно делается.

Или другой вариант, тоже мне кажется хорошим решением: в том месте, где я вызываю эту функцию передавать тип User. Но тоже непонятно, можно ли прокидывать типы от функции к функции вглубь.

### Дополнение

Понял что что пример выше не годится для понимания вопроса.
Распишу более подробно что делает функция и в каком виде возвращается объект.

**1. базовая функция для отправки запроса на сервер**

вырезал все что не относится к вопросу.

```
const fetch = (url, method, data) => {
  const fetchConfig = buildFetchConfig({ method, data }); // Дополнительная функция, где определяются заголовки, префиксы, методы и прочее..

  return $fetch(url, fetchConfig)
        .then((res) => res)
        .catch((error) => error);
};
```

Она может вернуть объект двух типов успех/ошибка (см. начало вопроса).

**3. Класс, реализует две метода**

```
class Request {
  static get(url, params) {
    return fetch(url, 'get', params);
  }

  static post(url, body) {
    return fetch(url, 'post', body);
  }
}
```

**4 ну и собственно набор роутов, делающих реквест**

```
class User {

  static auth() {
    return Request.get('user/auth');
  }

  static login(body) {
    return Request.post('user/login', body);
  }
}


class Book {

  static add(body) {
    return Request.post('book/add', body);
  }
}
```

Реализация хромает еще причешу.

Все функции и методы в данном пример общие, то есть могут вызываться из любого участка кода с разными аргументами, которые и должны определять возвращаемый тип объекта.

В моем примере единственное место, где я уже точно знаю, какой тип мне должен вернуться - это методы `User.auth()` `User.login..` и т.д.

А теперь как обращаюсь к `User.auth()` и какой тип получаю

```
  const res = await UserApi.auth(); // const res: any

  // соответственно, код ниже уже не дает никакой подсветки

  if (res.status === 'ok') {
    this.user = res.data.somevar; // не показывает ошибку.
  }
```

**Что ожидаю получить и что пробовал**

Пробовал добавить тип в метод `auth()` таким образом:

```
type ApiResponse<T> = SuccessResponse<T> | ErrorResponse

static auth(): Promise<ApiResponse<User>>  {
```

И это работает

```
const res = await UserApi.auth(); // const res: ApiResponse<User>

if (res.status === 'ok') {
    this.user = res.data.somevar; // TS2339: Property 'somevar' does not exist on type 'User'
}
```

Но не определяет, какой тип возвращают остальные функции. Можно ли как-то динамически определить тип для них, когда аргументы определяются только в методах классов User и Book?

То есть, по-хорошему, еще на этом (самом верхнем уровне) я должен определять тип, и прокидывать его в глубь, к самой первой функции. Предполагаю что это в таком кейсе в тайпскрипте это делается именно так по цепочке. Возможно есть какое-то другое решениt. Опыт с TS только получаю.

Comment: "динамически поменять тип" - именно этим и славится JS :)

Comment: "можно ли прокидывать типы от функции к функции вглубь" - можно генериками

Comment: Но TS делает типизацию контролируемой. Чтобы при наведении на функцию с определенными параметрами, (в моем примере) мы уже могли видеть какой тип она вернет.

Comment: добавь пример как ты хочешь использовать и что хочешь получить.

Comment: @Grundy дополнил вопрос

Comment: добавь пример вызова с типами, чтобы было видно где должна быть ошибка и какой тип где возвращается/передается

Comment: а пример вызова так и не добавил :)

Comment: @Grundy, всё, максимально расписал

Comment: а чем не устраивает объявление типов на уровне функций в `User`? Какой тип для `body` подразумевался? Сейчас он считается за `any`

Comment: на уровнe user  объявлю, но не знаю, как задать типы для всех остальных функций по цепочке. То есть в моем примере они так и остаются обычными функциями без типов. Но надо же, чтобы они понимали, что когда возвращается ответ от сервера то это объектj определенного типа (user или book). body - это какой-то объект передаваемый на сервер методом post, задать для него тип не проблема. Указав его наверху в user он пойдет вниз по цепочке. А вот как задать тип для уже полученных данных - вопрос..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятно при каких условиях какие типы должны получаться, но вот простой пример как такое можно сделать:

```
// Определяем возвращаемые типы для методов, все строки можно вынести в енумы
type MethodReturnTypes<T> = {
    "get": T;
    "post": null;
};

// Получаем список всех доступных методов для удобства
type Methods = keyof MethodReturnTypes<never>;

// Определяем доступные пути
type UserPaths = `user/${"login" | "auth"}`;
type BookPaths = `book/${"add"}`;

// Задаём типы методов для каждой группы путей
type PathMap =
    & { [path in UserPaths]: MethodReturnTypes<User>; }
    & { [path in BookPaths]: MethodReturnTypes<Book>; };

// Получаем список всех доступных путей для удобства
type Paths = keyof PathMap;

type Response<P extends Paths, M extends Methods> = PathMap[P][M];

type t1 = Response<"book/add", "post">; // null
type t2 = Response<"user/auth", "get">; // User
```

Функцию для работы с этим можно определить так:

```
function fetch<P extends Paths, M extends Methods>(url: P, method: M): Response<P, M>;

const t1 = fetch("book/add", "post"); // null
const t2 = fetch("user/auth", "get"); // User
```

Answer (score -1):

[Документация](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html). Немного геморный вариант, но рабочий:

```
interface IUser {
    name: string,
    age: number
}

interface IBook {
    name: string,
    author: string,
    pages: number
}

enum Paths {
    AUTH = '/use/auth',
    BOOK = 'book/add',
}

enum Methods {
    GET = 'GET',
    POST = 'POST',
}

type objectType<T, K> = 
    T extends Paths.AUTH ? K extends Methods.GET ? IUser : null : null &
    T extends Paths.BOOK ? K extends Methods.POST ? IBook : null : null;


function getObject<T, K>(path: Paths, method: Methods): objectType<T, K> {
    return {} as any;
}

getObject<Paths.AUTH, Methods.GET>(Paths.AUTH, Methods.GET) // IUser
getObject<Paths.BOOK, Methods.POST>(Paths.BOOK, Methods.POST) // IBook
```

Comment: Могу ли я передать сюда `getObject<Paths.AUTH, Methods.GET>` строковые значения из переменной?

Comment: Не понял. Имеете ввиду так `getObject<'/use/auth/', 'GET'>`?

Comment: Да или может быть можно напистаь условие внутри `objectType` например T === '/use/auth/' и  K === 'GET' или прокинуть T и K функцию, которая сама вернет true false...

Comment: @engenes Я перестал понимать что вам надо :) Эти условия уже написаны тут `T extends Paths.AUTH ...` и он в зависимоти от данных возвращет тот тип, что вам надо. Это же самые обычные тернарные операторы, в чём именно проблема возникает?

Comment: Можете [тут](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) поиграться с TS и увидеть результаты экспериментов